# Arcore: How can I get the dimensions of an image that I placed on the surface?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I have placed an image on a surface and I am trying to display the height and width of the image when I tap on it (having an idea to select and resize later).

I am converting the TransformableNode to an imageView and then using getHeight() and getWidth(). but is there a simple way provided by ARCOre?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert TransformableNode in Box type and get the size of the box:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created a project like Google measure App where I am scaling the node placed and then getting its size. Here is the link: [Object Measurement](https://github.com/shubh261096/measurementapp)